# Specify #lang for eval in Racket

Tags: racket

I want to use a specific #lang in eval to provide it its semantics. However, eval itself does not appear to have a mechanism to specify the language, and passing in #lang does not seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`make-module-evaluator`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsandbox..rkt%29._make-module-evaluator%29%29) from [`racket/sandbox`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html) for that.

```
> (require racket/sandbox)
> (define evaluator (make-module-evaluator "#lang racket/base"))
> (evaluator '(+ 1 2))
3
> (evaluator "(+ 1 2)")
3
```